# Azure web roles locally start on the wrong port

Tags: azure, ssl, localhost, azure-web-roles

I have a simple web application which we recently moved over to Azure.  Running in the local Azure emulator and on IIS Express, in the WebRole I have set it to run on `https://localhost:12345`, but when I run the project it comes up on `http://localhost:63855/`.  Completely different port and a distinct lack of HTTPS.

Thank you in advanced,

Andrew

Comment: I discovered the issue.  In the ServiceDefinition.csdef file, the InputEndpoint was set to use http, not https.  I also discovered if a port is taken, the Azure emulator has a concept of Port walking which keeps incrementing the port number until it finds a free port